# Using PHP variables within echo quoted string?

Tags: php, function, variables

How can I use ucwords($firstname) within `echo ""`? ie

```
<?php
$firstname = "john";
$surname = "smith";
echo "Welcome ucwords($firstname) ucwords($surname)";
?>
```

Comment: You can use variables just fine. You're basically asking for evaluating abritary code in strings, which is a wholly different matter.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<?php
$firstname = "john";
$surname = "smith";
echo "Welcome " . ucwords($firstname) . " " .  ucwords($surname);
?>
```

Like this.

Answer (score 3):

```
echo "Welcome" .  ucwords($firstname) . " " . ucwords($surname);
```

EDIT:

Alternative pattern:

```
$firstname = ucwords($firstname);
$surname = ucwords($surname);

echo 'Welcome $firstname $surname';
```

Comment: can it be done inline, without breaking the string? using {}?

Comment: You could do something like $firstname = ucwords("john"); then echo "Welcome $firstname"   Not sure it makes much difference though.

Comment: That's what I had before, looks like its the only way. Thank you.

Comment: Not exactly. I made an edit to fully explain the alternative (rather than crappy comments code). See if that is more copacetic to your tastes. Only measurable gain from using the alternate is that if you needed the names upper cased again, later in the script, you would not need to run ucwords() a second time.

Answer (score 2):

Like this:

```
<?php
$firstname = "john";
$surname = "smith";
echo "Welcome " . ucwords($firstname) . " " . ucwords($surname);
?>
```

or this:

```
<?php
$firstname = "john";
$surname = "smith";
$format = "Welcome %s %s";
printf($format, ucwords($firstname), ucwords($surname));
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
echo "Welcome " . ucwords($firstname) . " " . ucwords($surname);
```

Answer (score 1):

It's hacky in the extreme, but you can use variable functions for this:

```
$uc = 'ucwords';
$firstname = 'fred';
$lastname = 'jones';

echo "Welcome {$uc($firstname)} {$uc($lastname)}";
```